Would it be possible to use a Cygnus resupply spacecraft as a temporary space station?
The Cygnus spacecraft used for resupply missions to the ISS is built by Orbital Sciences.  The Mission B variant is due to fly next year and has an internal volume of 36 cubic metres,  (1,300 cu ft) and a design life of 2 years.
Would it be possible to avoid the development problems of designing a new station and use an off-the-shelf one of these as a stop-gap space station if Axiom et al don't have their space stations available when the ISS is deorbited?
Cygnus has its own power supply but probably not life support, that would have to be provided by visiting craft as is planned for the Haven-1 station.
I notice this idea is not in the CLD proposals.

To what end? The Cygnus hull is derived from an ISS module so it's not out of the question, but what would it be used for?

Well it could do the same job as Haven-1 but without the development costs and timescales - "Haven-1 will house a microgravity research facility called the Haven-1 Lab, which will serve as the station's microgravity research, development and manufacturing platform. [snip] The first companies to agree to place payloads on Haven-1 have been announced as Redwire and Yuri Gravity"  . And then there's space tourism.  It wouldn't be in the same league as Axiom's station or Orbital Reef, but if time was running out for the ISS and the new stations had the usual project overruns...

Technically, yes.  I've actually spent the duration of writing this answer convincing myself it's a better and better idea.  However:
To what end?
Organic Marble's comment hits it on the nose:  what tasks is the station for?  Does an off-the-shelf Cygnus offer the same amount of power?  Space?  Control?  Just looking at the Wikipedia articles in your question:

The station will be unable to sustain itself over a long period of time and will rely on the Crew Dragon for long-term missions by using its life support systems. Using Dragon, the station will be capable of sustaining 4-crew missions with 24/7 communication facilities, up to 1,000 watts of power, up to 150 kg of preloaded cargo mass, and science, research, and in-space manufacturing opportunities for up to 30 days.
...
Haven-1 will house a microgravity research facility called the Haven-1 Lab, which will serve as the station's microgravity research, development and manufacturing platform. It will have 10 slots, each capable of accommodating payloads weighing up to 30 kilograms and consuming up to 100 watts of power

versus

The [Cygnus] SM is capable of producing up to 4 kW of electrical power via two solar arrays.
...
The fourth and all subsequent Cygnus spacecraft are the "Enhanced" variant. These have a stretched PCM with a length of 6.39 meters (21.0 ft), a payload capacity of 3,500 kilograms (7,700 lb), an increase of 32%, and a pressurized cargo volume of 27 cubic metres (950 cu ft),

This ancient Cygnus factsheet that hilariously depicts MCC Houston as the VAB indicates (if I'm reading it correctly) each cargo slot on Cygnus gets 150W average power.
Okay, wow. Haven-1 seems broadly inferior on the simplest figures of merit (available power, available payload) compared to just using a Cygnus, though it does have more pressurized volume.  Well, nobody ever said newspace investors knew what they were doing.
That said
What difficulties might you have with a Cygnus in particular

The existing Cygnus has a CBM berthing adapter, not the IDSS docking that is currently the accepted international standard for crew transfer.  I'd assume that's actually different for the Cygnus-variant HALO for Lunar Gateway (and the renderings seem to confirm that).  The Cygnus HALO module development honestly probably pretty closely hews to what you'd want out of a LEO Cygnus station.

Some control and flight software development might be necessary to support both allowing other vehicles to dock with it and occupied usage for microgravity science; ISS has the niceties both of being absolutely gigantically enormous and having Control Moment Gyros in addition to thrusters for attitude control.  A smaller vehicle is more sensitive to the perturbations from its crew, potentially narrowing the envelope of useful microgravity science that can be done there.
Going back to HALO and Lunar Gateway more generally as a reference, note that the 2022 configuration is all logistics and habitation, not laboratories like ISS.  Not to say that you can't do work to make a Cygnus into a usable lab space, but I was talking myself into thinking HALO had done all that already and I don't think it has; certainly HALO at least relies on some of the other Gateway modules for important functions, and even just "why are we putting this heap into a lunar halo orbit when we could stick it in LEO and do useful science maybe" might require additional work to support that.


Overall
I think this is doable and honestly could probably be The Entire Shtick of a newspace company (paying Northrop Grumman to make the appropriate flavor of Cygnus / take the HALO off their hands during the chaos expected in 2025 NASA).
I do think that to be more than a tourist destination you would want to have specific requirements for duration of undisturbed freefall, power per experiment slot, volume per experiment slot, mass per experiment slot, etc developed in concert with microgravity scientists or any commercial microgravity manufacturing entities that exist.  You need more than just a powered cylinder with air in space; it has to have some additional useful qualities.

"You need more than just a powered cylinder with air in space; it has to have some additional useful qualities"  Indeed, I was surprised the Haven-1 was viewed as a serious proposal; it would be a successor to the ISS but in name only. I suppose Vast see Haven-1 as a way into credibility/funding for their bigger stations and perhaps Orbital (or is it Northrop Grumman now?) had their hands too full designing the Lunar Gateway variant of Cygnus to be thinking about an LEO version.

@DaveGremlin Northrop-Grumman bought out Orbital ATK in 2018
